# Is there any RecyclerView/UITableView equivalent in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Currently doing a Vue.js project that renders a list that has thousands of rows and this causes the whole page to become painfully slow. Any updates to the list will take very long time to complete the re-rendering. 
Is there any RecyclerView/UITableView equivalent in Vue.js that releases off-screen views/containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this package:
[vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller)